# R update single column with multiple join operations

Tags: r, left-join

I have

```
df1 <- data.frame(A = c("Andy", "Tim","Joe","Mike"), B = c("Andrew", NA,NA,"Michael"))
```

and

```
df2 <- data.frame(A = c("Andy", "Tim","Michael"), status = c("sent", "sent","sent"))
```

I would like to left join df1 to df2 with either A or B from df1 matching A from df2. The result would be what is produced by:

```
result <- data.frame(A = c("Andy", "Tim","Joe","Mike"), B = c("Andrew", NA,NA,"Michael"), status = c("sent", "sent", NA, "sent"))
```

Comment: Hi! What have you tried and what is not working? You should show us this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
library(dplyr)
left_join(df1, df2, by = c("A" = "A")) %>%
  left_join(df2, by = c("B" = "A")) %>%
  mutate(status = coalesce(status.x, status.y)) %>%
  select(-status.x, -status.y)
#      A       B status
# 1 Andy  Andrew   sent
# 2  Tim    <NA>   sent
# 3  Joe    <NA>   <NA>
# 4 Mike Michael   sent
```

Comment: Just what I was hoping for, thanks. It was the coalesce that was missing. I still need to see what happens with coalesce if there is a value in status.x and status.y, but so far this seems to work and I was otherwise going down a convoluted path with many lines of code using ifelse and replacing values where there is an NA.

Answer (score 0):

If you have lot of columns in `df1` that you want to join you can get the data in long format.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df1 %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -row, 
               values_drop_na = TRUE) %>%
  left_join(df2, by = c('value' = 'A')) %>%
  group_by(row) %>%
  fill(status, .direction = 'updown') %>%
  pivot_wider() %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-row)

#  status  A     B      
#  <chr>  <chr> <chr>  
#1 sent   Andy  Andrew 
#2 sent   Tim   NA     
#3 NA     Joe   NA     
#4 sent   Mike  Michael
```